# Task Runner Configuration Missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 and opened a solution I had been working in with Visual Studio 2015. It seems like everything works great except that the task runner explorer in VS 2017 is not detecting the package.json file in one of my projects so it is giving me the message "No task runner configurations were found." My package.json is in the same folder as my solution file and I added it into the proper project by creating a file link. VS 2015 had no problem with this and I'm not sure why VS 2017 does or how to fix it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found the [NPM Task Runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner) in the Visual Studio Marketplace that fixed my problem. After installing it, the package.json file showed up in Task Runner Explorer.

Also, don't forget to set your system path to be the top priority for the External Web Tools by going into Options > External Web Tools and moving $(PATH) up the list. My npm scripts were failing until I did this as well.

Comment: Changing the path priority did the thing for me... Good job!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem after upgrading VS to version 15.6.2. Have tried to moved $(PATH) up the list BUT it does not fix the problem - can't find tasks. Any idea?

Comment: Additional on my comment above. I notice that problem only on project that is Folder based. It works well for Solution based project (e.g. ASP MVC.sln).

Answer (score 24):

The Task Runner Explorer can be found via the menu **View > Other Windows > Task Runner Explorer**.

This is how you find it or you can use the search window in the top right and search for Task Runner and it will show up.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My problem wasn't finding the Task Runner Explorer window, but rather once it was open it couldn't find my package.json file. However, your answer might help others who get here because they can't find the window.

Comment: I used to be able to just right click on my gruntfile.js and select task runner explorer.  Any ideas how I can get that back?

Answer (score 11):

If you got here because your `webpack.config.js` is not showing up in the Task Runner Explorer, it's because webpack is not supported by default.

You must install Mads Kristensen's [WebPack Task Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner) from the Extensions and Updates window in Visual Studio.

Or install Web Essentials 2017 which includes the WebPack Task Runner, and a number of other awesome tools from Mads.

Comment: Thanks for this!  For me, the plugin was installed but it became disabled on its own for some reason.

Comment: @Greg_Gum: I just added the author of the **WebPack Task Runner** which helped me to identify the correct extension, maybe it is just because my extension-search is weirdly sorting and filtering.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered a similar problem when attempting [this introductory Typescript tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-core.html). The option to run task runner explorer was not there, when I expect it should have been.

The solution was odd, but it worked. The file I wanted to deal with was in a subfolder, like this:

[image]

Note the lack of 'Task Runner Explorer' in the rightclick menu.

I then moved the file into the main folder for the project:

[image]

and now it works as expected.

[image]

**Quick update:**

In case the images stop showing (which seems to be an issue on some answers):

The solution is to **place the file in the root folder of the project**.

Comment: this did the trick in VS2019 Version 16.8.6. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Task Runner Explorer is not shown in "View/Other Windows/Task Runner Explorer" menu if "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools" extension is disabled. However if to enable it and to disable the "Microsoft Azure App Service Tools" extension then Task Runner Explorer will appear in the "View/Other Windows" menu but will not work.

So answer is following: both "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools" and "Microsoft Azure App Service Tools" extensions should be enabled for Task Runner Explorer to work. 
Tested on Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.2 (26430.16)

Answer (score 3):

Although I have successfully been using `Task Runner Explorer` for other projects, even last night for example, all of a sudden today (11/17/2018) it stopped working. The solution was to go to `Tools->Extensions And Updates` and search (upper right corner) for `NPM Task Runner` and when it found that extension, I clicked the `Enable` button next to it. It gave me a warning that I needed to close and reopen Visual Studio 2017, and when I did, the `-vs-binding` for `BeforeBuild` in my `package.json` started working, and the items in Task Runner Explorer looked correct and started working again.

Comment: @Kent_Weigel: There are many search results for `NPM Task Runner` (at least in my version and configuration of Visual Studio), I assume you mean https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner

Comment: @B--rian: I only get one result with that exact wording. I clicked your link, and it seems to be the same one...written by Mads Kristensen, and the features look the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install [Bundler & Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier) extension for VS. You can install it from VS Tools > Extensions and Updates.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem obvious to me that this would resolve the issue. Do you have an explanation of why installing that extension causes VS to recognize the package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

This is a contextual menu option. If you have bundleconfig.json highlighted (or something else that is appropriate) in visual studio 2017 you will see it in tools and if you don't... then it will always be in view/other windows

Answer (score 0):

If you're already running [Mads' Webpack Task Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner&ssr=false#qna) and still not seeing tasks, please note that the plugin only recognizes the file named *webpage.config.js*

If you named it anything else - like webpack.MyProject.js - then Task Runner won't display your tasks.