# Webpack throws error when compiling simple Vue file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

When I run webpack watch in the VS2017 task runner it throws this error:

```
ERROR in ./wwwroot/js/src/App.vue
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (****\node_modules\vue-loader\index.js:1:80)
at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at loadLoader (****\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:18:17)
at iteratePitchingLoaders (****\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
at runLoaders (****\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
at NormalModule.doBuild (****\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:182:3)
at NormalModule.build (****\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:275:15)
at Compilation.buildModule (****\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:157:10)
at factoryCallback (****\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:348:12)
at ****\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:243:5
at ****\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:94:13
at ****\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:268:11
at NormalModuleFactory.<anonymous> (****\node_modules\webpack\lib\CompatibilityPlugin.js:52:5)
at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (****\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:272:13)
at ****\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:69:10
at ****\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:196:7
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)
```

The App.vue file is a simple test file:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>XXX{{ sources.length }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        data() {
            return {
                sources: []
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    #app {
        font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        text-align: center;
        color: #2c3e50;
        margin-top: 60px;
    }

    h1, h2 {
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

    a {
        color: #42b983;
    }
</style>
```

This works fine on another machine so I can't understand why it's throwing this error. I'm not that familiar with webpack/vue/typescript etc and would appreciate some help. The error message is useless.

Comment: Remove node modules. Update node and then ```npm i ```. then it may work.

Comment: Thanks Hasibul - tried that but it didn't make any difference. It seems to be caused by vue-loader but I've no idea what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the vue-loader module did the trick, through the task runner was still showing an error it was building correctly when webpack --watch --color was ran in powershell:

```
npm install vue-loader@14.2.2
```

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1177

...the problem in Visual Studio was that Task Runner was using the webpack in node_modules/.bin folder. To rectify this, go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Package Management and move the $(PATH) entry to the top of the list (as per [Task Runner Configuration Missing in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674832/task-runner-configuration-missing-in-visual-studio-2017))